# Order rows based on different column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have data in table in following format.

```
CustomerID | CustomerName | DisplayOrder | isActive
1 | Test | 1 | 1 
1 | Test | 2 | 1 
2 | Test2 | 1 | 1 
1 | Test | 3 | 1 
2 | Test2 | 2 | 1
```

Above table need to be sorted based on displayorder column per customer. Each customer will have thier own display order. Here I cannot use OrderBy Clause direcly because Display order will repear per customer.

Expected Output is:

```
CustomerID | CustomerName | DisplayOrder | isActive
1 | Test | 1 | 1 
1 | Test | 2 | 1 
1 | Test | 3 | 1 
2 | Test2 | 1 | 1 
2 | Test2 | 2 | 1
```

Please help on order by clause to sort based on customer.

Comment: `SELECT * from mytable order by customerId, displayOrder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to sort by customerId and then display order (if customer id is same) like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY customerId, displayOrder;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79a2aa/2) for the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY CustomerID,
         DisplayOrder;
```